# @Inject for Hilt is giving UninitializedPropertyAccessException

Tags: android, kotlin, inject, dagger-hilt

I am using Hilt in my project, and it is working fine everywhere apart from this one file.

```
abstract class SomeFile {
  
    @Inject
    lateinit var useCase: UseCase

    fun setData() {
       if (useCase.driver == 1){ do something }
       else { do something }
    }
}
```

This same "UseCase" inject is working in another files like viewmodel and activity. But only in this abstract class file is where I am getting this exception. What could be the issue here?

Module class

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object HiltUseModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun getUseCase(stateMachine: StateMachine): UseCase {
        return createProxyInstance(stateMachine)
    }
}
```

The app doesn't crash or anything. It just goes to the if condition and doesn't do anything. I used debug to check what is the value of 'useCase' there, and it shows the exception UninitializedPropertyAccessException.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you added @AndroidEntryPoint above your abstract class?

Comment: It gives this error if I try to add this annotation to abstract class- @AndroidEntryPoint base class must extend ComponentActivity, (support) Fragment, View, Service, or BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: what is usecase? interface? and did you create instance of ``statemachine`` via dagger-hilt? what is createProxyInstance()? seems like function, is it?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than field injection, you should use constructor injection to acquire an instance of `SomeFile`.

```
class SomeFile @Inject internal constructor(private val useCase: UseCase) {
  fun setData() {
    if (useCase.driver == 1){ do something }
      else { do something }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, you will need to inject this into some component which is an entry point (whether that's your `ViewModel`, `Fragment`, or `Activity`:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint(AppCompatActivity::class)
class MyActivity : Hilt_AppCompatActivity() {
  @Inject internal lateinit var someFile: SomeFile

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    someFile.setData()
  }
}
```

Comment: I had an intermittent issue with an injected property not being initialized. It was injected on a subclass, but the `init` block in the superclass class was calling a function, the overridden version of which was referencing the injected property. Moving it into the constructor resolved this for me too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
abstract class SomeFile {
 
    fun setData(useCase : UseCase) {
       if (useCase.driver == 1){ do something }
       else { do something }
    }
}
```

What it does is that the parameter that you pass in function will find object of UseCase from wherever it can.

Comment: Tried this. Didn't work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

Inject dependencies in classes not supported by Hilt

If you need to perform field injection in classes that Hilt doesn't support.

you need to use `@EntryPoint` annotation

```
  @EntryPoint
  @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
  interface MyEntryPoint {
    fun getUseCase(): UseCase
  }
```

and access user class using

```
val hiltEntryPoint = EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(appContext,MyEntryPoint::class.java)
val useCase = hiltEntryPoint.getUseCase()
```

Comment: My class is abstract, and @EntryPoint works with interface only.